# One Link to Change One Boolean Attribute from false to true without using a form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I need to be able to click a button or a link that will change a boolean attribute in a model from false to true without using a form. There is already a form on the page that creates a new instance of the model and I don't want the resulting conflict between the two forms being on one page. So, I have an `ItemResponse` model, with a boolean called `accept` - and I want my link "Accept Offer" in the partial to change it to true and refresh the page.

My controller:

```
class ItemResponsesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :accept]
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy


  def create
    @item_response = current_user.item_responses.build(response_params)
    if @item_response.save
      flash[:success] = "Item Response created!"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
    else
      @item = @item_response.item
      render 'items/show', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item_response.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Item Response deleted"
    redirect_back_or_to( root_url, status: :see_other )
  end

  def accept
    @item_response.update_attribute(:accept, true)
    if @item_response.save
      flash[:success] = "Item Response Accepted!"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
    else
      @item = @item_response.item
      render 'items/show', status: unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

    def response_params
      params.require(:item_response).permit(:item_id, :message, :offer, :pickuporship)
    end

    def correct_user
      @item_response = current_user.item_responses.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other if @item_response.nil?
    end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  default_url_options :host => "localhost:3000"

  root "static_pages#home"
  get  "/help",    to: "static_pages#help"
  get  "/about",   to: "static_pages#about"
  get  "/contact", to: "static_pages#contact"
  get  "/signup",  to: "users#new"
  get  "/login",   to: "sessions#new"
  post "/login",   to: "sessions#create"
  delete "/logout",to: "sessions#destroy"
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations,   only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,       only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :items,                 only: [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]
  resources :looking_for_items,     only: [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]


  resources :item_responses,        only: [:create, :destroy, :accept]
  resources :item_responses do
    member do
      get "accept"
    end
  end


  resources :looking_for_responses, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

and my partial for the item responses:

```
<li id="item_response-<%= item_response.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(item_response.user, size: 30), item_response.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to item_response.user.name, item_response.user %></span>
  <span class="message"><%= item_response.message %></span>
  <span class="offer"><strong>Offering $<%= item_response.offer %></strong></span>
  <span class="pickuporship">
    <% if item_response.pickuporship %>
      <%= " Will Pick Up Item" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= " Want Item Shipped" %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(item_response.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(item_response.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete response", item_response, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                            "turbo-confirm": "Are you sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% if item_response.accept %>
    <%= "Accepted!" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= "Not Accepted" %>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Accept Offer", accept_item_response_path(item_response) %>
</li>
```

finally, my model for ItemResponse:

```
class ItemResponse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  attribute :accept, :boolean, default: false

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :item_id, presence: true
  validates :message, length: { maximum: 2000 }
  validates :offer, presence: true,
                    numericality: { only_integer: true },
                    inclusion: 0..10000
  validates :pickuporship, inclusion: [true, false]
  validate :offer_matches_item_asking_price
  validate :pickuporship_matches_seller_preference
  validates :accept, inclusion: [true, false]

  def offer_matches_item_asking_price
    theitem = Item.find(item_id)
    errors.add(:base, "The seller is not accepting OBOs - please match their asking price") unless ( theitem.obo == true ) || ( theitem.askingprice == offer )
  end

  def pickuporship_matches_seller_preference
    theitem = Item.find(item_id)
    errors.add(:base, "Please select a pickup or ship option that matches the seller's preference") unless ( theitem.pickup == true && pickuporship == true ) || ( theitem.willship == true && pickuporship == false )
  end

end
```

When I try clicking the aforementioned link, I get an error:

`` undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass ``

So something is wrong with @item_response - it's expecting a form? Do I actually need to make this into a form? Or do I need to use turbolinks like I do when I'm deleting/destroying something?

Comment: it's expecting an `@item_response`, which is not set anywhere for `accept` action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So something is wrong with @item_response - it's expecting a form?

No. You're just calling a method on an instance variable that you haven't actually defined. It's a classic beginner footgun in Ruby.

> I need to be able to click a button or a link that will change a boolean attribute in a model from false to true without using a form.

### Wrong.

In reality you **absolutely** want to use a form since this is a [non-idempotent action](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html) that updates a resource on the server.

Sending non-idempotent requests (POST) with a browser is done with forms. Links send GET requests. GET requests are stored in the browsers history and hitting the back button should not lead to unexpected consequences.

In Rails you would handle this with `button_to` which creates a form with just a single button or the Rails UJS or Turbo handler for links with the `data-method` or `data-turbo-method` method.

The real difference is just that the later uses a bit of javascript trickery to create a form that's not attached to the DOM and submits it. It's a less rubust and accessible approach but can be used inside of a form (nested forms are not permitted in HTML).

What you actually should be doing:

```
resources :item_responses do
  patch :accept, on: :member # the correct HTTP method to use here is debatable
end
```

```
class ItemResponsesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  # This fixes the nil error 
  before_action :set_item_response, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :accept]

  # PATCH /item_responses/1/accept
  def accept
    if @item_response.accept
      flash[:success] = "Item Response Accepted!"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_url)
    else
      @item = @item_response.item
      render 'items/show', status: unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  #  ...

  private

  def set_item_response 
    @item_response = ItemResponse.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```
<% if item_response.accepted? %>
  Accepted!
<% else %>
  Not Accepted
  <%= button_to "Accept Offer", 
    [:accept, item_response], 
    method: :patch
  %>
<% end %>
```

```
class AddAcceptedToItemResponses < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    # use the correct adjective form and set the default in the schema
    add_column :item_responses, :accepted, :boolean, default: :false
  end
end
```

```
class ItemResponse < ApplicationRecord
  # You do not need or want to define attributes if they correspond to a database column
  # You also have so much other garbage in the this model. 
  # - belongs_to assocations are required by default.
  # - you do not need to validate inclusion of booleans. Especially not when they are not set from user input.
  # - default_scope is considered evil
  # ...
  def accept
    update_attribute(accepted: true)
  end
end
```

Comment: On a side note I would use a date / datetime column named `accepted_at` instead as does the same thing but provides more actual utility.

Comment: I followed your instructions, and when it tries to render the item_response, I get an error `undefined method 'item_response_accept_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000001ca48>` for the code `<%= button_to "Accept Offer",
    [item_response, :accept],
    method: :patch
  %>`

Comment: changed it to `<%= button_to "Accept Offer",
    [:accept_item_response],
    method: :patch
  %>` and the page renders, with the button, but the button doesn't do anything, it remains "Not Accepted". when I try to go to my browser and type in `http://localhost:3000/item_responses/1/accept`, I get `No route matches [GET] "/item_responses/1/accept"`

Comment: oops - I forgot that it's doing GET from the browser, not PATCH.

Comment: aha!  `<%= button_to "Accept Offer",
    [:accept, item_response],
    method: :patch
  %>` this worked perfectly, just had to switch the arguments for button_to code

Comment: Ooops, yeah. You can also explicitly call the route helper.  `accept_item_response_path(item_response)`